# Globally change UIBarButtonItem text color when selected or highlighted

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have `UIToolbar` (inside my `UINavigationController`) with some `UIBarButtonItem`s on it.

Toolbar is `blue` (`isTranslucent = false`), button is `white`. Default highlight color is `gray` and it looks ugly.

The only solution I found is to change `UIBarButtonItem`'s `tintColor` in `@IBAction` touch event. But I have many `UIBarButtonItem`s and its pretty annoying to write a plenty of code in every `@IBAction`.

Do you know how to change it globally or, at least, subclass `UIBarButtonItem` to define it once and use this class everywhere?

*I use swift 3, deployment target is iOS 9+*

Comment: You may add UIButton in side barbutton item then you may can manage that.

Comment: Maybe you are looking to do something like subclass `UIButton`, override the touch events, and then call the super? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151246/uibutton-subclass-ibaction-not-working

Comment: @dfd something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43044276/2193926 but for `UIBarButtonItem`, not for `UIButton`

Comment: Not sure if this helps any better, but if you want to override `touchesBegan`, etc., they are part of `UIToolbar`.

Comment: @dfd I can't do it in `UIToolbar` because I need to highlight each `UIBarButtonItem` on toolbar separately. If I change `UIToolbar`'s TintColor all my buttons will change color, not the only one selected.

Comment: Ah. My bad. (That's what the deleted answer suggested, and I knew it wouldn't work.) I agree. My last thought - and a lot of coding - is to somehow (a) subclass `UIToolbar` or create your own to (b) use a subclassed `UIButton` with overridden touch events. Whatever you do, good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function in your `AppDelegate` witch tells the delegate that the launch process is almost done and the app is almost ready to run.

And in there you can use the `appearance` on your `UIBarButtonItem` and `UINavigationBar`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Text
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green], for: .normal)
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.darkGray], for: .selected)

    // Images
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.orange

    return true
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: It looks exactly what I need, but it does nothing in my application. I don't know why. I create my items like this `let button = UIBarButtonItem(image_name: buttonIconName, title: buttonTitle, target: target, action_selector: buttonAction)` `self.setToolbarItems([flexible_space, button, flexible_space], animated: false)`

Comment: It works with "text only" buttons. Thats works: `let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "test_text", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)` Thats doesn't: `let button = UIBarButtonItem(image_name: "test_image", title: "test_text", target: self, action_selector: nil)`

Comment: You mean that it doesn't work with images @JohnKakon?

Comment: oh, I found `extension UIBarButtonItem` in my code that make it work wrong =) my mistake, sorry. Your code was correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [appearance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance) to change color globally. Add next lines in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
    [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white], for: .selected)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
    [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white], for: .highlighted)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 4.2

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIColor.green], for: .normal)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIColor.darkGray], for: .selected)
```